# scaffold all guid's in asp.net dynamic data by default

Tags: c#, dynamic-data, scaffolding, asp.net-dynamic-data

is there an option to scaffold all guid columns in asp.net dynamic data by default?

I know there's the possibility to set the ScaffoldColumn attribute to true in this way:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyEntityMetadata))]
public partial class MyEntity
{}

public partial class MyEntityMetadata
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    public Nullable<global::System.Guid> DataValueG { get; set; }
}
```

but I don't want to specify always two additional classes for every guid column...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute.scaffoldcolumnattribute.aspx), "You can set scaffold to true for the entire data model to expose all data columns in the database ... by setting scaffold to true in the Global.asax file or expose individual data columns in a data table to CRUD operations by setting scaffold to true in the partial class."

```
DefaultModel.RegisterContext(typeof(MyDataContext), new ContextConfiguration() { ScaffoldAllTables = true });
```

Comment: This does not fix the issue/problem he is having.